# Bot code needs help identifying when to interact with keywords

Tags: python, discord.py

Needless to say, I'm botting/coding for the first time and I've hit a wall.
Essentially, I want the bot to reply when recognizing a keyword, but said keyword is short so it can fit in regular words.

An imitation of the code I have is:

```
if 'A' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send('xyz')
```

So if you would say 'Apples', the bot would chime in with 'xyz'.

I'm just looking for the bot to engage with isolated instances within a sentence only, such as 'A dog'.

How would I go about formatting this code where it can identify the distinction between (for example) the A in 'A dog' as apposed to the A in the word 'Apples' or just a message containing 'A'?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: You question is unclear, could you elaborate more by giving inputs/outputs examples.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you could do it in this way:

see all the word in the message.content for example doing a list and do something like
 if "word" in list_of_words:
do something

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language you are using. It might be helpful to include that piece of information in the future just so folks can zero in on a possible solution quicker. Anyway in Python, I think using regular expression like this might work:

```
import re
match = re.search(r"tri", "A string")
if match:
    pass #process(match)
```

If the "A string" is to be used more than once, then it might be more efficient to compile it first.

If this solution works for you and you'll like to learn more then [Python RegEx from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) is a good source.